# Ruby on Rails error when importing "bootstrap"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to ruby on rails, and currently following Michael Hartl's tutorial and unfortunately get stuck on chapter five when I try to call the `@import "bootstrap";` in the custom.css.scss file.

I get the following error:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetFilteredError in StaticPages#home
  Showing /Users/name/Documents/Rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts    /application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( glyphicons-halflings.png )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
      (in /Users/name/Documents/Rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/styleshee
/custom.css.scss)
     Extracted source (around line #5):

line 5:    stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"
```

Having combed the internet I’ve tried the following solutions, none of which worked

1. the suggestion provided above for the assets.rb file
2. restarting the server with control+c
3. moving the gem file ‘bootrap-sass’into the section in gem file for
   assets not required in product
4. changing the extension name of the application.css file to
   application.css.scss
5. directly calling @import “bootstrap”; in the application.css.scss
   file
6. adding to config.ru the following: require 'bootstrap-sass' #require
   statement of bootstrap-sass

These are all solutions I found on the web, but none work.

Appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you trying to add?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.1...

Comment: my answer should work with rails 4.1 as well

Comment: Wali Ali - thank you very much! this seems to be working now, but what call do I make in custom.css to get bootstrap since i'm not using @import anymore?

Comment: no call needed. you create a file with extension .css. example: custom.css (inside app/assets/stylesheets) and you immediately start typing your css code. save it and refresh your browser. maybe also restart server (just the first time). and it should work.

Comment: accept the answer if all works out. let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you were able to get the issue sorted out, but this is what I did to get things working.

the error

```
Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( glyphicons-halflings.png )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

tells you to actually put

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( glyphicons-halflings.png )
```

in your

`config/initializers/assets.rb` path

After I did that, I got another similar error but this time with another line to be added.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( glyphicons-halflings-white.png )
```

Now, you also need to make sure that you the `@import "bootstrap";` line in your `application.css` file in path `app/assets/stylesheets/` directory and rename the file to `application.css.scss`

After putting these above both `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` lines in the `config/initializers/assets.rb` file and then restarting the server, it actually worked for me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

Another way of integrating bootstrap with Rails 4.x is:

download the bootstrap version you want. unzip the file and save it in your local machine. Then move the documents to the relevant folders in your asset pipeline. Like this:

move all javascript files (the file extension ends with `.js`) to `app/assets/javascripts`

move all css files(file extension ends with `.css`) to `app/assets/stylesheets`

move all images to `app/assets/images`.

inside the `app/assets/stylesheets`, create a custome file `custom.css`. you can use the file to override bootsrap functionality. you won't need the `@import` method. 
you also don't need to add a gem in your in your `Gemfile`. just download the version of bootstrap you want and follow the directions above.

I believe the tutorial uses [bootstrap 2.3](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2)